# Remove class that starts with certain word and add it to its parent

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'd like to accomplish this:

- Look at the target element
- If it has a class name that **starts with** `custom_`
- Then remove that class name and add it to parent of the target element

I think I can use the `is` function to find whether the element has that class, I just don't know how to remove that class and move it up one element.

`if ( target.is( "[class^='custom_'],[class*=' custom_']" ) )`

Comment: `removeClass()` and `$(target).parent().addClass()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the class on spaces, use regex to check if each one matches your condition, remove those that match, add them to the parent:

```
var target = e.target;
var matched_classes = $(target).attr('class').split(' ').filter(
    function(c) { 
        return /^custom_/.test(c)
    }
).join(' ');
$(target).removeClass(matched_classes).parent().addClass(matched_classes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to get the class name, then act accordingly.

```js
var target = $('#target'),
    className = target.attr('class').match(/custom_*\w/)[0];

target.removeClass(className).parent().addClass(className);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="target" class="class1 class2 custom_3 class3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good enough?

```
var $target = $('div.foo'),
    classPrefix = 'custom_';

if($target.is('[class^="'+ classPrefix +'"]')){

    var matchingClass = $target[0].className.split(' ').filter(function(className){
        return ~className.indexOf(classPrefix);
    })[0];

    if(matchingClass)
        $target.removeClass(matchingClass).parent().addClass(matchingClass);

    console.log($target.parent(), $target);
}
```

Edit: Looks like I was late to the party

http://jsfiddle.net/0a7m69kv/1/